# Zurb foundation framework - 100% height grid

Tags: height, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb's foundation 12-column grid on my site and it's all built out and scaling well, unfortunately, I need the background of the site to be black and everything in the grid to be white. When I set the body to be black, the grid doesn't scale full-height so there is black underneath. Does anyone know of way to make the grid 100% height, either with CSS or JS?

Comment: Please add some code or example...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use css with height `100%` to main row or the container row and positioning them absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
```

e.g.

```
<div class="row expanded">
    <div class="small-10 columns" style="min-height: 100vh; max-height: 100vh;">A</div>
    <div class="small-2 columns">B</div>
</div>
```

vh is viewport height and the viewport is the browser part that is visible for the website

Div A is going to always going to have the height of the viewport and if you resize the height of the browser the two divs are going to resize also.

I know my answer is late for the OP but I struggled with this problem and maybe I can help someone else.

Cheers